# Photolysis of water

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

Photolysis of water releases $\text{O}_2$, $\text{H}^+$ ions and $\text{e}^-$.

$\text{Mn}$ in the $\text{O}_2$ evolving complex also produces $\text{e}^-$.

What provides $\text{e}^-$ to [P680](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P680):$\text{Mn}$ and water?

Comment: Can you clarify your sources and where this information derives from? Even though this is related to fundamental biochemistry that every undergraduate learns, it's still good for us to understand what your materials are.

Comment: Consider [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Photosystem_II_-_multilingual.svg) from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosystem_II).